# How to properly reference the same entity from multiple navigation properties in an EF model

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework

I have been tasked with making a simple time tracking program and thought it would be a good time to learn how to use some basic entity framework features. I created a DB model and am currently putting together the DB using the diagram editor.

I am used to making databases in MySQL with workbench and am not totally used to thinking of my database entries as eventual objects.

Here is my situation:
I have to store some "presets" of workdays. For example, preset `normal` would apply 9AM-5PM as the working hours from Monday to Friday and `not working` on Saturday and sunday.

Basically, when it comes to manipulating the data, I want to be able to do something like: `week.preset.monday.start` and get a time back so that I can eventually draw fancy colorful graphics :).

Here is an image of what I *think* is going to work:
[image]

Is this the correct way of doing this (using multiple navigation properties and deleting them on the WorkdayPreset side)?

Comment: Are the presets user-defined? In other words, can the user change the presets themselves as part of some configuration process, or will they always be the same presets that the user can chose from?

Comment: Good question! I intend to allow the users to set up their own presets as over time shift patterns may change.

Comment: Why not just have a collection of Workdays in your Workweek class and add a DayOfWeek enum attribute to the workday?

Comment: Oh that's a good one Steve! I like it! Seems much cleaner.

Comment: Not sure you even need a workweek class. You could get monday start with something like context.WorkDays.Single(wd => wd.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.MONDAY).Start